# KoGrid update cell

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I am trying to update a single cell with KoGrid, but I don't see the update happen until I sort the grid by clicking on the column header.

The following is the code I'm using. JSFiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/b22Ex/2/

The line that's not working is: vm.data()[0].b(100). Shouldn't that work since the value is a ko.observable?

```
    var L = [
        {a:ko.observable('a1'), b:ko.observable('b1'), c:ko.observable('c1')},
        {a:ko.observable('a2'), b:ko.observable('b2'), c:ko.observable('c2')},
        {a:ko.observable('a3'), b:ko.observable('b3'), c:ko.observable('c3')}
    ];
    var vm = {
        data: ko.observableArray(L)
    };
    window.vm = vm;
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    vm.data()[0].b(100)
    console.log("DONE CHANGING VALUE");
```

By the way, I also came across [KoGrid how to refresh grid in case data is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642798/kogrid-how-to-refresh-grid-in-case-data-is-changed)
but I don't want to update the entire dataset.

Comment: Have you tried making the update be a function from a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Try this :

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b22Ex/9/)

*JS*

```
var xxx = [
    {a:ko.observable('a1'), b:ko.observable('b1'), c:ko.observable('c1')},
    {a:ko.observable('a2'), b:ko.observable('b2'), c:ko.observable('c2')},
    {a:ko.observable('a3'), b:ko.observable('b3'), c:ko.observable('c3')}
];

var vm = {
    data: ko.observableArray(xxx),
};

window.vm = vm;
ko.applyBindings(vm);

 vm.data()[0].b(100);
 vm.data.valueHasMutated();  //This will update your observable in UI


console.log("DONE CHANGING VALUE");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and it works. Is there a particular reason I have to call valueHasMutated()?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution to your problem. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/b22Ex/5/).

```
var xxx = [
 {a:ko.observable('a1'), b:ko.observable('b1'), c:ko.observable('c1')},
 {a:ko.observable('a2'), b:ko.observable('b2'), c:ko.observable('c2')},
 {a:ko.observable('a3'), b:ko.observable('b3'), c:ko.observable('c3')}
];
var vm = {
 data: ko.observableArray(xxx)
};
window.vm = vm;
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.data()[0].b(100)

vm.data(vm.data()); //This line will make the fix that you need.

console.log("DONE CHANGING VALUE");
```

Comment: Instead of reinitialize the observableArray, you can use `valueHasMutated` property which will automatically propagate the changes to UI, check my updated answer